# Reading a list stored in a text file

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, file

I have a file whose content is in the form of a python list such as the following:

```
['hello','how','are','you','doing','today','2016','10.004']
```

Is there any way to read the python file back into a list object? instead of using `.read()` and having the whole file just read as a string.

EDIT: for those who may be interested i ran into a strange issue using (import ast) as suggested as a solution for the above problem.

the program i used it in has a function which fetches historical stock data from the yahoo finance python module. this function is in no way related or dependent on the function which used ast.literal_eval().

anyways every night after market close i collect new batches of historical data from yahoo finance and last night i ran into an error : simplejson.scanner.jsondecodeerror expecting value.

it was strange because it would collect data just fine for some companies but throw the error for others, and sometime work for the same company but a minute later it would not work.  after trying all kinds of things to debug and solve the issue remembered that the import ast was recently added and thought i should try to see if it could have an effect, after removing the import ast the program went back to workin as it normally did.

does anybody know why import ast caused issues? @Apero why did you initially warn against using eval or ast.literal_eval?

Comment: Do you control how the file was saved?  If so, you had to write the list as a string, can you modify that process so you don't have to deal with this complication

Comment: file was created in python using  f.write(str(my_list))

Comment: Rewrite the file with: `f.write(' '.join(map(str, mylist)))`

Comment: @Apero:  `['this data', 'would not round trip']`

Comment: If your file used double quotes, you could use `import json ; data = json.load(open("filename.txt"))`

Comment: Indeed, the json approach is clean too, but "safe" json never starts with a list. A list should always be wrapped into a dict notation like ``{"results": [1, 2, 3, 4]}``

Comment: What does the input look like? If it's JSON, using the `json` module would be the right way to handle the data.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    mylist = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: Never, ever, ever use ``eval`` or ``ast.literal_eval``. That's the best advice I received when I started coding in python.

Comment: @Apero: "never, ever" is bad advice. `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` are tools that serve a specific purpose. When you understand how they work and what they do, there is no reason to avoid them under the right circumstances. Instead of saying "never, ever use them", say "gain a deep understanding before using them".

Answer (score 16):

1. rename the file from i.e. ***foo.txt*** to ***foo.py***
2. add `my_list =` in front of that line
3. in your code: `import foo; l = foo.my_list`

Simpler, no? ;-)